# How to get Months from a given quarter

Tags: java, java-time, localdate, date

I'm trying to get Months from a certain quarter. Using the code below, I successfully get the names of the months in the current quarter from the LocalDate.now() instance.

How would I get a quarter's months from just a quarter String (e.g. "Q1")?

```
int monthInt = Month.from(LocalDate.now()).firstMonthOfQuarter().getValue();
      for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) { //for each month in quarter
          System.out.println(Month.of(monthInt).name()); //January, February, March
          monthInt++;
      }
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, the mapping from a quarter string like `Q1` to the month names is constant, right? `Q1` always means Jan-Mar.

Comment: I used `int  quarter = LocalDate.now().get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR);` initially, where IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR is constant and made it to a string.

Comment: So you don't have a quarter string, but a quarter `int`?

Comment: I have a quarter string, which was initially an int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can find out how the JDK calculates the quarter by looking at the declaration of `getFrom` of `IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR`:

```
public long getFrom(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
    if (isSupportedBy(temporal) == false) {
        throw new UnsupportedTemporalTypeException("Unsupported field: QuarterOfYear");
    }
    long moy = temporal.getLong(MONTH_OF_YEAR);
    return ((moy + 2) / 3);
}
```

Notice how it uses the formula `quarter = (moy + 2) / 3`. Therefore, to find the starting month of a quarter, we just need to rearrange it in terms of `moy` - `moy = quarter * 3 - 2`.

You can write a method like this:

```
private static List<String> monthNamesFromQuarter(int quarter) {
    // you can do the validation of quarter yourself
    int start = quarter * 3 - 2;
    return IntStream.range(start, start + 3)
            .mapToObj(Month::of)
            .map(Month::name)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was wondering if there was an API solution but this works just as good.

Comment: There is an API to find the start of the quarter given a _month_, but since you said you have a quarter number, you need some maths here. @xblaz3kx

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

Use [`org.threeten.extra.YearQuarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) class, along with [`Quarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html), [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html), [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html), and [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html).

```
YearQuarter                         // Represent an entire quarter of a specific year.
.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) )   // Determine the current quarter as seen via the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). 
.with(                              // Move to another quarter.
    Quarter.valueOf( "Q1" )         // Or, `Quarter.of( 1 )` if starting with an integer number rather than a `String` object.
)                                   // Returns another `YearQuarter` object, rather than modifying the original.
.atDay( 1 )                         // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.getMonth()                         // Returns a `Month` enum object.
.getDisplayName(                    // Automatically localize the name of the month. 
    TextStyle.FULL ,                // How long or abbreviated do you want the translation.
    Locale.US                       // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH and so on. 
)                                   // Returns a `String` object.
```

> January

## `YearQuarter` in *ThreeTen-Extra*

The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library has a class you might find useful for this work: [`YearQuarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html).

Get the current quarter. We need a time zone to determine the current date, and therefore the current quarter. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
YearQuarter currentYearQuarter = YearQuarter.now( z ) ;
```

But you want to determine a quarter by parsing a string.

If you have a string styled similar to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (the standard does not actually specify quarters) `YYYY-Qq` then `YearQuarter` can [directly parse](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)).

```
String input = "2020-Q1" ;
YearQuarter yearQuarter = YearQuarter.parse( input ) ;
```

If you have only the quarter part without the year, use [`Quarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html) enum. If your input string is `Q1` and such, use [`valueOf`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) to retrieve the matching enum object.

```
String input = "Q1" ;
Quarter quarter = Quarter.valueOf( input ) ;
```

If you have a number instead of a string, that is, `1` or `2` or `3` or `4`, then use static method `Quarter.of`. By the way, in your own code you should be passing around these `Quarter` objects rather than a mere integer or string, to make your code more self-documenting, to provide type-safety, and to ensure valid values.

```
int input = 1 ; // Domain: 1, 2, 3, 4. 
Quarter quarter = Quarter.of( input ) ;
```

Apply that `Quarter` instance to our current `YearQuarter` instance to get another `YearQuarter` instance. These classes use the [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern, so we are not modifying existing instance, we are generating new instances.

```
YearQuarter yearQuarter = currentYearQuarter.with( quarter ) ;
```

> yearQuarter.toString(): 2019-Q1

Get first date ([`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html)), and year-month ([`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html)), and [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum object, from that year-quarter.

```
LocalDate firstDate = yearQuarter.atDay( 1 ) ;
YearMonth yearMonth1 = YearMonth.from( firstDate ) ;
YearMonth yearMonth2 = yearMonth1.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
YearMonth yearMonth3 = yearMonth1.plusMonths( 2 ) ;
```

Generate a string containing the [automatically localized](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) name of month.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH and so on. 
String output1 = yearMonth1.getMonth().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , locale ) ;
```

> January

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: FYI, there is also a `firstMonth()` method on `Quarter`: https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html#firstMonth()

Answer (score 2):

I suggest we build a map of the months contained in each quarter and make a simple map lookup whenever we need the months for some quarter string. A stream pipeline and an adequate `DateTimeFormatter` will build such a map in just a few lines:

```
static Map<String, List<Month>> monthsPerQuarter = Arrays.stream(Month.values())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("QQQ", Locale.ENGLISH)::format));
```

IMO the great advantage here is that we need to do no math ourselves. While math converting from quarter number to month number may seem simple for the person writing it, it is not only error-prone, it will also be unclear and hard to decipher for many readers.

Now we can lookup for example like this:

```
    System.out.println(monthsPerQuarter.get("Q3"));
```

Output is:

> ```
> [JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER]
> ```

If you need the months individually:

```
    monthsPerQuarter.get("Q4").forEach(System.out::println);
```

> ```
> OCTOBER
> NOVEMBER
> DECEMBER
> ```

If your quarter was originally a number in the range from 1 through 4, you may use this map instead:

```
static Map<Integer, List<Month>> monthsPerQuarter = Arrays.stream(Month.values())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR)));
```

A reason why I recommend the map approach is: it’s easy to convert from `Month` to quarter string, but java.time offers no easy way to convert from quarter string to month. Just for the demonstration and not the way I recommend, one might do:

```
    DateTimeFormatter quarterFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("QQQ")
            // Any year will do since all years have the same 4 quarters @ the same 3 months
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, 2000)
            .parseDefaulting(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1)
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

    String qString = "Q1";
    Month firstMonthOfQuarter = Month.from(quarterFormatter.parse(qString));
    IntStream.range(0, 3)
            .mapToObj(firstMonthOfQuarter::plus)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

> ```
> JANUARY
> FEBRUARY
> MARCH
> ```

It’s 11 code lines instead of 4 with no gain that I can see.

Comment: That's a pretty nice and clean solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For `quarter > firstmonth` the rule is

```
Q1 -> 1
Q2 -> 4
Q3 -> 7
Q4 -> 10

With math : quarterValue *3 -2
```

So applying this in Java :

```
String quarter = "Q1";
int monthInt = Integer.parseInt(quarter.replaceAll("\\D", "")) * 3 - 2;
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    System.out.println(Month.of(monthInt + j).name());
}
```

---

```
List<String> quarters = Arrays.asList("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4");
for (String quarter : quarters) {
    System.out.print(quarter);
    int monthInt = Integer.parseInt(quarter.replaceAll("\\D", "")) * 3 - 2;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        System.out.print(" " + Month.of(monthInt + j).name());
    }
    System.out.println();
}

Q1 JANUARY FEBRUARY MARCH
Q2 APRIL MAY JUNE
Q3 JULY AUGUST SEPTEMBER
Q4 OCTOBER NOVEMBER DECEMBER
```